# Node.js callback functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose

I'm new to the Node.js platform and I'm trying to learn as much as I can. After playing with callbacks one thing really confuses me:

So, I have this function :

```
    function registerUser(body, res, UserModel){

    var userJSON =  {
        email : body.email,
        password : body.password,
        accessToken : null
    };
    var user = null;
    var userAlreadyExists = false;

    UserModel.find({}).select('email').exec(function(err, results){
        if(err){
            console.log('Database error : ' + err);
         // send the appropriate response

        }else{
            for(var index in results){
                if(results[index].email == userJSON.email){
                    userAlreadyExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(userAlreadyExists){
                // send the appropriate response
            }else{
                  newAccessToken(UserModel, function(error, token){
                    if(error != null){
                           // handle the error
                    }else{
                        userJSON.accessToken = token;
                        user = new UserModel(userJSON);
                        user.save(function(err){
                            if(err){
                               // .. handle the error
                            }else{
                               // .. handle the registration
                            }
});}});}}});}
```

And then the function which accepts the callback:

```
function newAccessToken(UserModel, callback){

    UserModel.find({}).select('email accessToken').exec(function(err, results){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
          // .... bunch of logic for generating the token
            callback(null, token);
        }

    });
}
```

I would expect the callback to not work(maybe throw an error) since both `user` and `userJSON` are not defined in it's context.(well, that's not exactly true, but since it is executed async - after a while - , I would expect the callback to lose it's references to those variables, which were defined locally in the `registerUser` function). Instead this example works perfectly, the callback function keeps it's references with those two variables defined in the `registerUser` function. Could somebody explain me how the async callback and the references work and why does the example work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H i, the function you 'calllback to' is **within** the scope of the variables you are trying to access, so all good to go for accessing them.

This is not a nodejs thing, regular JS works the same way .

**The difference**

1) Will not be able to access a var called 'foo'

```
function finishfunction() {
  console.log(foo); /*  undefined */
}

   function functionwithcallback(callback) {
       callback();
  }

  function doStuff() {

     var foo = "bar";

    functionwithcallback(finishfunction);

 }

 doStuff();
```

2) like yours, access to 'foo' is fine.

```
   function functionwithcallback(callback) {
       callback();
  }

  function doStuff() {

     var foo = "bar";

    functionwithcallback(function() {

    console.log(foo) /* all fine */

    });

 }

 doStuff();
```

Comment: even if the closure is executed after 5 mins for example, it will still keep the references towards those variables?

Comment: yes, all stays in scope. Give it a try. I call these just regular callbacks btw (a timed function being 'called back' when it is done ). Closures, ( a function in a function), would be better named for objects(functions) with methods and private variables, and are updating the privately scoped variables of the object(function) from multiple sources.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of callbacks, those are called closures, and in JavaScript the scope treatment is special. Check this document:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: so the closure keeps it's references with the variables defined in the main function even if the closure is executed after some period of time like 1 minute for example?

Comment: Yes, don't worry about time, the function is executed within the scope of the calling function.